# How to achieve this without refreshing the page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page that populates a table via jQuery.

Since I only want to change classes of a particular `<td>` element I used `replaceWith`. This worked well on the first search, but I realized that I could not asynchronously perform another search without first refreshing my page. I then tried `html` instead of `replaceWith`. This worked well, but crammed all the new `<td>` into one `<td>` that has the specified id.

How can I achieve this without refreshing the page so that I can get the `<td>` elements well distributed?

**Before updating:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>first row</td>
<td>measure1</td>
<td>measure2</td>
<td>measure3</td>
<td>measure4</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First row</td>
<td id="no_rec" colspan="4"> No record to display!</td>
<td>More+</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**After updating I expect to have a table of the format:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>first row</td>
    <td>measure1</td>
    <td>measure2</td>
    <td>measure3</td>
    <td>measure4</td>
    <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>First row</td>
    <td class="new"></td>
    <td class="new"></td>
    <td class="new"></td>
    <td class="new"></td>
    <td>More+</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**My JavaScript:**

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() 
{
    $.post
    (
        'search.php', 
        {
            regNo: $("#regNo").val(),
            datepicker: $(".datepicker").text()
        },
        function(data) 
        {
            $.each(data, function(i) 
            {
                var tm = data.time;

                add_html='';

                for (i=0; i<4; i++)
                    (i === 0 || i === 2) 
                        ? add_html += '<td class="new"></td>' 
                        : add_html += '<td></td>';

                $('#no_rec').replaceWith(add_html);
            });
        },
        'json'
    );
});
```

**[My JsFiddle Attempts](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4HF4B/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was add `id=results` to the `tr` so that I could find and store all `td` tags and then manipulate them accordingly.

## ***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ga6a/)***

All notes are left in the comments of the jQuery, but one that I should mention here is that I added a `simulateData()` function that basically allows you to click the `Update` button as many times as you want to see how the code will handle different data that's returned.

## ***HTML***

---

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>first row/measures</td>
        <td>measure1</td>
        <td>measure2</td>
        <td>measure3</td>
        <td>measure4</td>
        <td>measure5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="results">
        <td>First row</td>
        <td colspan="4">No record to display!</td>
        <td>More+</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button>Update</button>
```

## ***jQuery***

---

```
var noRecord = "<td colspan=\"4\">No record to display!</td>",
    currentTime = 0;

$( "button" ).click( function ()
{    
    var $results = $( "#results" ),              // Get the TR.
        $tds = $( "#results" ).find( "td" ),     // Get the TDs within the TR.
        data = simulateData();                   // Simulate data.
    
    // Check to see if data was returned.
    
    if ( data === undefined )
    {
        // Data was not returned.
        
        if ( $results.html().indexOf( noRecord ) === -1 )
        {
            // Results TR has previous values that need to be removed.
            
            for ( i = 1; i < 5; i++ )
                $( $tds[i] ).remove();
       
            // Add back the [No record to display!] TD.
            
            $( noRecord ).insertAfter( $tds[0] );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Data was returned.
        
        $.each( data, function ( i ) 
        {
            // Store the current data.
            
            var tm = parseInt( data.time );
            
            // Check to see if the Results TR has previous values or not.
            
            if ( $results.html().indexOf( noRecord ) > -1 )
            {
                // Results TR does not have previous values.
                
                var html = "";
                
                // Generate new TDs.
                
                for ( i = 1; i < 5; i++ )
                    html += "<td class=\"new\">" + tm + "</td>";
                
                // Remove [No record to display!] TD and replace with new TDs.
                
                $( $tds[1] ).replaceWith( html );
            }
            else
            {
                // Results TR has previous values so we need to loop 
                // through each existing TD replacing its class and value.
                
                for ( i = 1; i < 5; i++ )
                {
                    if ( i != tm )
                    {
                        // Change class to "new" and add stored data value.
                        
                        $( $tds[i] )
                            .removeClass( "rr" )
                            .addClass( "new" )
                            .text( tm );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Change class to "rr" and add "ee" value.
                        
                        $( $tds[i] )
                            .removeClass( "new" )
                            .addClass( "rr" )
                            .text( "ee" );
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});


// This simulates the async calls to search.php to generate 
// different times on each click of the Update button.

function simulateData()
{
    // Increment our simulated time.
    
    currentTime++;
    
    if ( currentTime > 4 ) 
    { 
        // Start over by resetting our incrementer.
        
        currentTime = 0; 
        
        // Simulate a call that doesn't return data.
        
        return undefined;
    }
    else 
    {
        return { "time": currentTime }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response that solve the prob at hand. However I tried to extends this to similar prob I have with no success see my JS Fiddle here [JS Fiddle Sample](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4HF4B/)

Answer (score 0):

> Since I only wants to change classes of perticular  element I used replaceWith

[replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method entirely replaces all matching elements with the new content.

for simply changing the css class you can use

> [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass)
> adds the specified class to matched elements
>
> [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass)
>
> removes the specified class from matched elements
>
> [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass)
>
> adds the class if it's not applied, removes it if it's already applied

Comment: I considered `addClass` but since I have used `colsspan="4"` in the html will `addClass` still be relevant?

Comment: Yes, If you can provide your script and proper html or a http://jsfiddle.net/ it'll be easier to help.